# Request failed with status code 405 React Native Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-native, laravel-5, axios

I am having **Request failed with status code 405** error when submitting the post request from React Native and using Laravel 7 in the backend.

```
const data = {
...
}

const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Method": "POST",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

axios.post(API_URL, data, headers).then((response) => {
    consoleLog("token", response.data)
    if (response.data) {
        this.setState({
            bkashURL: API_URL + response.data,
            loading: false,
        })
    }
})
```

**Laravel Route:**

```
Route::post('/', 'PaymentController@processInput');
```

[image]

Please help.

Comment: please also post the laravel route and whatever else seems relevant for this issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Request failed with status code 405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439902/error-request-failed-with-status-code-405)

Comment: pls check the edited version.

Comment: what is the `API_URL`? where is the `PaymentController.php` located?

Comment: if you are calling the API from the emulator, the API should URL should not be a `http://localhost` URL but a `http://10.0.2.2` one

Comment: its not localhost its in live

Comment: try to call the API using Postman or something similar and see if you get the expected result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218622/discussion-between-wahidsherief-and-cornel-raiu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed further in the chat, it seems that the problem was a typo in the API call.

The solution is to just add a trailing slash to the api URL to match the route:

`whatever.url/api/whatever/abc` - will trigger 405

`whatever.url/api/whatever/abc/` - will work